# Getting CefSharp browser to show in Window.Content

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I've been reading up on how to implement `CEF` with `WinForms` and have been able to reproduce implementing it on my own using Forms. What I need to do though is instead of using the `Form` class and setting its content to the `CEF` browser, I want to use `System.Window` and have it load the CEF browser. It seems like getting it to show in the same manner does not work for me

Example of it working

```
CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser cBrowser = 
  new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
Form form = new Form();
form.Controls.Add(cBrowser);
form.Show();`
```

What I want to do is this

```
System.Window window = new System.Window();
CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser cBrowser = 
   new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
window.Content = cBrowser;
window.Show();`
```

But using the `Window` class does not show the browser at all. Any ideas as to why?  If I use the WebBrowser class object and set that to the `Window`. Content it works but not if I use the browser that `CefSharp` generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First example works because it uses an object with WinForms understand: Form.
Second example does not work because you are using wrong class in WinForms. 
In WinForms everything is a form.

the Window class is from the presentation framework.  You will have to use WPF application if you want to use the Window class.

And if you want to use WPF, you will have to use CefSharp.WPF nuget package.

Comment: That helped. I had got the nuget package for Wpf but it was not loading the Wpf dll's into my project.  Had to clean up and re install the package in order to get it to work properly.  Thanks!